# Most recent order from multi join query

Tags: t-sql, join

Here's the CTE version of the query, but it is returning multiple rows for the same customer. Not just the row containing the most recent open order date:

```
with LatestOPenOrderDate_CTE AS
(
  Select Customer, OpenOrderDate = Max(OpenDate)
  from Orders
  group by Customer
)

select 
    o.Customer, Branch, 
    con.Name as Closer, o.GFNO, 
    o.UserDate1 as CancelDate, 
    OpenDate, 

    o.AgentSeller as SellerAgentNum,
    dbo.wtAgentName(o.AgentSeller) as SellerAgentName,
    dbo.wtAgentContactName(o.AgentSeller) as SellerContactName,

    o.AgentBuyer as BuyerAgentNum,
    dbo.wtAgentName(o.AgentBuyer) as BuyerAgentName,
    dbo.wtAgentContactName(o.AgentBuyer) as BuyerContactName,

    Lender,MortgageBrokerID,
    Service,
    OrderCategory, SalesPrice, LoanAmount,SourceOfBusiness,
    dbo.wtGetPropertyField (o.GFNO, 'Address') As  PropertyAddress, 
    dbo.wtGetPropertyField (o.GFNO, 'City') As  PropertyCity, 
    dbo.wtGetPropertyField (o.GFNO, 'State') As  PropertyState,
    dbo.wtGetPropertyField (o.GFNO, 'Zip') As  PropertyZip,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then dbo.wtagentname(o.agentbuyer)
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then dbo.wtagentname(o.AgentSeller)
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Lender%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(Lender,'Name')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Mortgage Broker%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(MortgageBrokerID,'Name')
    else 
      '' 
    end as PDCContactName,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(o.agentbuyer,'Phone')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(o.AcctBalance,'Phone')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Lender%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(Lender,'Phone')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Mortgage Broker%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(MortgageBrokerID,'Phone')
    else 
      '' 
    end as PDCPhone,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(o.agentbuyer,'Email')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(o.agentseller,'Email')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Lender%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(Lender,'Email')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Mortgage Broker%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(MortgageBrokerID,'Email')
    else 
      '' 
    end as PDCEmail,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then dbo.wtagentname(o.agentbuyer)
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then dbo.wtAgentName(o.agentseller)
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Lender%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(Lender,'Office')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Mortgage Broker%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(MortgageBrokerID,'Office')
    else 
      '' 
    end as PDCAgentName,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then o.agentbuyer
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then o.agentseller
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Lender%' then Lender
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Mortgage Broker%' then MortgageBrokerID
    else 
      '' 
    end as PDCAgentNum,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then dbo.wtagentname(o.agentseller)
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then dbo.wtagentName(o.AgentBuyer)
    else 
      '' 
    end as NDCContactName,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(o.agentseller,'Phone')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(o.agentbuyer,'Phone')
    else 
      '' 
    end as NDCPhone,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(o.agentseller,'Email')
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(o.agentbuyer,'Emal')
    else 
      '' 
    end as NDCEmail,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then dbo.wtAgentName(o.AgentSeller)
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then dbo.wtagentname(o.agentbuyer)
    else 
      '' 
    end as NDCAgentName,

    Case 
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Selling Realtor%' then o.AgentSeller
      when SourceOfBusiness like '%Listing%' then o.agentbuyer
    else 
      '' 
    end as NDCAgentNum,

    Case 
      when service in (1,4) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Lender%' then Lender
      when service in (3) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Mortgage Broker%' then MortgageBrokerID
    else
      ''
    end as NDLAgentNum,

    Case 
      when service in (1,4) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Lender%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(Lender,'Name')
      when service in (3) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Mortgage Broker%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(MortgageBrokerID,'Name')
    else
      ''
    end as NDLName,

    Case   
      when service in (1,4) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Lender%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(Lender,'Phone')
      when service in (3) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Mortgage Broker%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(MortgageBrokerID,'Phone')
    else
      ''
    end as NDLPhone,

    Case 
      when service in (1,4) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Lender%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(Lender,'Email')
      when service in (3) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Mortgage Broker%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(MortgageBrokerID,'Email')
    else
      ''
    end as NDLEmail,

    Case 
      when service in (1,4) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Lender%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(Lender,'Office')
      when service in (3) and SourceOfBusiness not like '%Mortgage Broker%' then dbo.wtGetAgentField(MortgageBrokerID,'Office')
    else
      ''
    end as NDLOffice

from orders o
inner join LatestOPenOrderDate_CTE L on L.Customer=o.Customer
left outer join dbo.CoNames con on con.Initials = o.CloseAgent

where OpenDate > '10-1-2015' and con.name is not null
order by o.Customer
```

Comment: Please also explain what rows your query should return, and give example input & desired output. Please read about MVCEs.

Comment: Seems like the query is very simple. No multiple joins, just one join of  two tables and a rather simple `where` clause. It would help if you added which table the `OpenDate` belongs to (we can guess it's the `orders` table but lets be sure) and if `CoNames (Initials)` is a `unique` key. Also, why your description says `OpenOrderDate` while the code has `OpenDate`? Is that two columns or one?

Comment: I removed the extra 2 tables the users could live without just to simplify things for my own understanding.  OpenDate is the field name and it is from the Orders table.

Answer (score 2):

The following pattern will often render very good performance, compared to self-joins and correlating subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CustomerID, c1, c2, c3
        ORDER BY OpenOrderDate DESC
        ) AS _rownum
    FROM some_table
    INNER JOIN ...
    INNER JOIN ...
    WHERE ...
    ) AS sub
WHERE sub._rownum=1;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a sequential number ordered by `OpenOrderDate` descending. By filtering on the output of this function, you can isolate the single-most recent row for each partition. Note the `PARTITION BY` clause, which defines how and when the row number function resets to 1.

Like @Erik points out, make sure that the combination of the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` columns generate a unique key.

Answer (score 1):

When I've had to do this in the past one easy pattern I've followed is below:

```
WITH LatestOpenOrderDate_CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    UserId
    , LatestOpenOrderDate = MAX(OpenOrderDate)
  FROM dbo.Foo
  GROUP BY
    UserId
)
SELECT
  L.UserId
  , F.OpenOrderDate
  , F.Bar -- Just here to show how to get the other data from the matched row
  , B.Buzz -- Just here to show adding a column from another join
FROM dbo.Foo F
  INNER JOIN LatestOpenOrderDate_CTE L ON L.UserId = F.UserId 
    AND L.LatestOpenOrderDate = F.OpenOrderDate
  INNER JOIN dbo.Baz B ON B.FizzBuzz = F.FizzBuzz -- Just here to show another join
WHERE
  F.OrderIsOpen = 1; -- Just here to show a WHERE clause
```

This works fine **as long as there aren't any duplicate dates for any given user**. If there are duplicate dates then you need to add extra columns to the CTE to prevent [spurious tuples](http://www.spurioustuples.net/about/whats-a-spurious-tuple/). There might be a better pattern for you to use, but I don't know what your existing query looks like.

Answer (score 1):

When you join from LatestOPenOrderDate_CTE to Orders, your only join criteria is Customer.  This will give you a one-to-many join, preventing the one-row-per-customer desired result.

Instead, you'll need to join on OpenDate as well, and potentially other criteria.

```
from orders o
inner join LatestOPenOrderDate_CTE L 
      on L.Customer=o.Customer AND o.OpenDate=L.OpenOrderDate
left outer join dbo.CoNames con on con.Initials = o.CloseAgent
```

That being said, consider thinking about the logic of your query in a different way--you might find that changing the way you think about the query will make your logic easier to follow.